# How to get idevice info by udid?

Tags: iphone, udid

I seen a website month ago that shows the general info of an iDevice, of them, it's type/ios version..etc

but i currently cant find it anymore, does anyone know what else can do the same process ?

Comment: Note that the getting the UDID of a device is now considered deprecated by Apple.

Comment: I think you are talking about [UIDevice class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

Comment: Simple way to find udid without iTunes is `udid.io`

Answer (score 1):

You can define the device type on your developer's account page in "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section. Unfortunately it contains only a small thumbnail of the device and also may include model's serial number (but not always)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get device information, such as the UDID, you can use this:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

If you want other information, such as orientation, system version, system name, etc, then just change uniqueIdentifier to the value you want. If you hold down option + esc or look at the link lawicko posted, then you can see some of your extra options.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the UDID or the Serial number?

The UDID is basically a SH1 hash of the serial number, ECID, wifiMAC, and the bluetoothMAC.
There is no public database of UDID's, so I doubt what you are refering to has to do with UDIDs.

If it involves the device's serial number, you can make reference to the site below:
https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do